# How to make nextflow use tmp directory of specific node?

Tags: nodes, hpc, nextflow

I have to run multiples nextflow pipeline in parallel, however, by doing so tmp/ directory becomes clogged up. Apparent reason is that while there are 30 different nodes available with large tmp/ directories, nextflow uses only the first one, which is filled pretty quickly so "not enough space" error is thrown out.

What i tried was running each nextflow pipe from one specific compute node, but how to make it use only tmp/ of this specific node?

Comment: My answer deals with the question in your title. Do you mean your jobs are filling up `/tmp` on your compute nodes? If so, you'll need to identify the process that is doing so and ensure it writes it's temp files locally in the Nextflow work-dir.

Answer (score 2):

The [scratch](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#scratch) directive will allow you to execute one or more of your processes in a temporary folder that is local to the execution node. If your temporary directory is defined by the `$TMPDIR` environment variable, you can use:

```
process myprocess {

  scratch true

  """
  <your script here>
  """
}
```

If your scratch directory is defined by some other variable, ensure it's wrapped in single quotes:

```
process myprocess {

  scratch '$TEMP_DIR'

  """
  <your script here>
  """
}
```